# How to distribute mysql with java application

Tags: mysql, innodb, installation, deployment

I have designed a free software in Java that uses a MySQL db at back end.
How could I distribute minimal MySQL (that is enough for performing basic SQL transactions) with my `jar` file. Currently I am using MySQL-essential installer but there are configuration problems with it on some PCs.

I thought of using the no-install version but it is too big (235 MB) for my application.

Comment: Check for licensing issues, too.

Comment: My question is there any way to minimal install of MySql, with distribution

Comment: Have you considered releasing your app as a docker container? The mysql database could be inside or simply pull the mysql image from the docker registry. Docker is becoming the ultimate way to package and distribute software.